# ¿Cómo exportar una BD de forma segura (encriptándola)?

Tags: mysql, linux, gpg

Estoy en el problema de que requiero exportar una BD pero me gustaría aprender a exportarla y encriptarla con GPG (usando encriptación simétrica). Mi comando queda algo como lo siguiente:

```
$ mysqldump -u user_db -p name_db | gpg -a --cipher-algo AES -o name_db.sql.gpg
```

Pero al ejecutarlo, mi terminal entra en modo espera y ni con <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> logro terminar el proceso. Cerré terminal y al volverlo a intentar, justo después de poner la contraseña MySQL, me salió:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
```

Tengo entendido que el *símbolo de canalización, tubo o pipe (en inglés)* "|" toma el contenido impreso del *comando1* para que el *comando2* pueda tomarlo, pero no logro hacer que funcione.

```
$ comando1 | comando2
```

**Nota:** No quiero guardar el archivo `.sql` y luego encriptarlo, más bien, quiero hacerlo sobre el mismo comando.

Comment: Asi es el ouput del primer comando debería ser el input del segundo, ¿has intentando agregando `--encrypt` al final de tu comando gpg? `gpg -a --cipher-algo AES -o name_db.sql.gpg --encrypt`

Comment: Si, era eso, me falta indicar el argumento de encriptar. Pero ahora tengo un problema, cuando me pide MySQL la contraseña de la BD, se sobre-escribe el comando de GPG y si no pongo la misma 3 veces, no lo encripta.

Comment: tu piensas poner el _passphrase_ manualmente ? o también quieres que sea entubado ?

Comment: @rnrneverdies si, ¿qué otra opción me recomiendas?

Comment: jaja.. estaba intentando otra cosa, utilizando --passphrase-fd 0, pense que querias meterlo todo en un comando _no interactivo_.

Comment: Te dejo un recurso en español bastante interesante: http://www.dewinter.com/gnupg_howto/spanish/gpgminicomo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era que te faltaba el flag para encriptar (`--encrypt`):

```
$ mysqldump -u user -p db | gpg -a --cipher-algo AES -o db.sql.gpg --encrypt
```

En ese punto tendrás dos inputs que agregar, la contraseña de la base de datos y el ID del usuario de tu gpg, en mi caso mi usuario es `"Cesar Bustios"`. En una línea:

```
$ mysqldump -u user -p"passworddb" db | gpg -a --cipher-algo AES -o db.sql.gpg --encrypt -r "Cesar Bustios"
```

El único  problema es que te saltará el warning de MySQL ya que es inseguro poner el password en la misma terminal.

Si el archivo existe te va a pedir confirmación, puedes pasarle el flag `--yes` al final para forzar la sobreescritura del archivo:

```
$ mysqldump -u user -p"passworddb" db | gpg -a --cipher-algo AES -o db.sql.gpg --encrypt -r "Cesar Bustios" --yes
```